# Styling individual elements in a pgf-umlcd diagram

Tags: pgf-umlcd

I'm aware that I can change the color of elements globally with e.g. `\renewcommand {\umltextcolor}{red}`. How could I give individual elements different colours or fonts? Assume the example below, where I want to give the `IMyInterface` box a blue background, and change the font of `MyImplementation` to monospace.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{interface}{IMyInterface}{0,0}
\end{interface}

\begin{class}{MyImplementation}{0,-2}
    \implement{IMyInterface}
\end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Edit:

One way to at least style the fill, text, and line colour is to explicitly specify `\renewcommand {\umlfillcolor}{Red}` etc. before each element. I still wonder if there is a better way, and a way to alter the font face itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass any option that is available for TikZ nodes to the pgf-umlcd elements as an optional argument to the environment. An example is given in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgf-umlcd/pgf-umlcd-manual.pdf) with the TikZ option `text width`:

```
\begin{class}[text width=8cm]{ClassName}{0 ,0}
```

In this case you can use the options `fill` and `font`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[simplified]{pgf-umlcd}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{interface}[fill=blue!20]{IMyInterface}{0,0}
\end{interface}

\begin{class}[font=\ttfamily]{MyImplementation}{0,-2}
    \implement{IMyInterface}
\end{class}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]